# Find the closure and then the galois group

Tags: galois-theory

So today on my test I had this problem: Find the normal closure and its Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}+\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$.

I managed to find the minimal polynomial during the test and got $$x^6+9 x^4-4 x^3+27 x^2+36 x+31$$
but from here I am not even sure of how to find the roots of this polynomial. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is not intended to find the minimal polynomial of that number; afteramm, the Galois group of a sixth polynomial is not very easy to find.Instead, one should generate the normal closure by some easier elements to examine the action of the Galois group, thus determining the group.That is only some personal view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One conjugate (the complex conjugate, in fact) of $\alpha=\sqrt{-3}+\root3\of2$ is $\beta=-\sqrt{-3}+\root3\of2$. Then $\alpha+\beta=2\root3\of2$ must be in the normal closure $N$, so also $\rho^j\root3\of2$ must be in $N$, where $\rho$ is a complex cube root of $1$, and $j=1,2$. So $\rho$ is in $N$, but note that we can take $\rho=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$. Putting this all together, I hope you can see that $N={\bf Q}(\rho,\root3\of2)$ is in fact the splitting field of $x^3-2$.

Now that we have the normal closure, can you get the Galois group?

Comment: So in fact the group is $\text S_3$? Thanks for this nice answer!